# Алгоритм Евклида

Tags: алгоритм, c++

Как написать алгоритм Евклида в наилучшем виде на С++? Какие его применения вы знаете?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Как насчёт [такого варианта](http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm)?

Рекурсивная версия.

```
int gcd(int a, int b) {
  if (b == 0)
    return a;

  return gcd(b, a % b);
}
```

Итеративная версия.

```
int gcd(int a, int b) {
  int t;
  while (b != 0) {
    t = b;
    b = a % b;
    a = t;
  }
  return a;
}
```

Зацикленная версия.

```
int gcd(int a, int b)
{
  while(true)
  {
    a = a%b;
    if(a==0)
    {
      return b;
    }
    b = b%a;
    if(b==0)
    {
      return a;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Отличная ссылка!

Answer (score 11):

Лучше реализовать [двоичный вариант](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm) алгоритма Евклида. У него меньше константа, скрытая в записи O(log(n)), т.к. деление на 2 гораздо быстрее, чем взятие остатка на современных процессорах.

Comment: Для тех, кто поленился пойти по ссылке. Под делением на 2 скрывается **сдвиг вправо на 1**.

Comment: Поправка: при написании алгоритма деление на 2 лучше все-таки оставить делением на 2, а не преобразовывать в сдвиг. Компилятор с такой работой справится и сам - а код будет более читаем.

Answer (score 7):

Я постоянно пишу так:

```
int gcd(const int &a, const int &b){return a ? gcd(b%a, a) : b;}
```

## Эксперимент

Стало интерессно, действительно ли деление так плохо и на сколько именно оно влияет на производительность. Сделал небольшой "бенчмарк":

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

/**
 * Different implementations of GCD algorithm
 */
int gcd(const int a, const int b) { return a ? gcd(b%a, a) : b; }

int iterable_gcd(int a, int b) { 
    int t;
    while (a) t = a, a = b % a, b = t;
    return b; 
}

int cycled_gcd(int a, int b) {
    for (;;) {
        a %= b;
        if (!a) return b;
        b %= a;
        if (!b) return a;
    }
}

int binary_gcd(int u, int v) {
    int shift, t;
    if (u == 0) return v;
    if (v == 0) return u;
    for (shift = 0; ((u | v) & 1) == 0; ++shift) {
        u >>= 1;
        v >>= 1;
    }
    while ((u & 1) == 0) u >>= 1;
    do 
    {
        while ((v & 1) == 0) v >>= 1;
        if (u > v) t = v, v = u, u = t;
        v = v - u;
    } 
    while (v != 0);
    return u << shift;
}

/**
 * Timers
 */
void timeit(int (*implementation)(int, int), const int from, const int to) {
    int i, j;
    struct timeval tv1, tv2;
    gettimeofday(&tv1, NULL);
    for (i = from; i < to; ++i) {
        for (j = from; j < to; ++j) {
            implementation(i, j);
        }
    }
    gettimeofday(&tv2, NULL);
    printf("Total time = %f seconds\n",
        (double) (tv2.tv_usec - tv1.tv_usec) / 1000000 +
        (double) (tv2.tv_sec - tv1.tv_sec)
    );
}

void timeit_small_numbers(int (*implementation)(int, int)) {
    const int from = 1000, to = from + 9*1000;
    timeit(implementation, from, to);
}

void timeit_big_numbers(int (*implementation)(int, int)) {
    const int from = 1000*1000*1000, to = from + 9*1000;
    timeit(implementation, from, to);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int (*implementations[])(int,int) = {
        cycled_gcd, 
        gcd, 
        iterable_gcd, 
        binary_gcd
    };
    const int size = sizeof(implementations) / sizeof(implementations[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) timeit_small_numbers(implementations[i]);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) timeit_big_numbers(implementations[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

- `gcd` - легко запоминается релазация не составляет труда реализовать.
- `cycled_gcd` - был предложен в одном из ответов, но он иногда даже хуже за `gcd`.
- `iterable_gcd` - рекурсия может накладывать свои расходы времени, поэтому добавил итеративный вариант, но толи флаг `-O3` делает свое дело толи эти расходы ну очень невелики
- `binary_gcd` - за основу взят [код с вики](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm#Iterative_version_in_C)

Если брать числа от 1000 до 10*1000 и от миллиарда до миллиарда + 9*1000 у нас будут разные результаты.

```
$ gcc -O3 run.c -o run
$ ./run
Test on small numbers
Total time = 8.311910 seconds
Total time = 8.329916 seconds
Total time = 8.333715 seconds
Total time = 7.837158 seconds
Test on big numbers
Total time = 10.425167 seconds
Total time = 10.481676 seconds
Total time = 10.460748 seconds
Total time = 17.428999 seconds
```

**На небольших числах** `binary_gcd` почти на **7% быстрее** любой из реализаций. Это очень даже хороший результат. Если конечно же вы уверены что у вас не будет больших чисел. Почему?

Потому что **на больших числах** `binary_gcd` быстро деградирует и уже показывает на **67% большее время работы** чем у остальных реализаций.

## Вывод

Реализации основанные на делении не так быстро деградируют хотя и уступают в производительности на небольших числах.

Answer (score 7):

Немного длиннее, но зато чуть быстрее, так как без рекурсии.

```
int gcd(int a,int b)
{
    while(a && b)
    {
        int c=a%b;
        a=b;
        b=c;
    }
    return a | b;
}
```